# How should GMP/MPFR limbs be interpreted?

Tags: gmp, mpfr

The arbitrary precision libraries GMP and MPFR use heap-allocated arrays of machine word-sized integers to store the limbs that make up the high precision number/mantissa.

How should this array of limbs be interpreted to recover the arbitrary precision integer number? In other words: for N limbs holding B bits each, how should I interpret them to recover the N*B bit number?

Does the limb size really affect the in-memory representation (see below)? If so, what is the rationale behind this?

---

#### Background:

I wrote a small program to look inside the representation, but I was confused by what I saw. The limbs seem to be ordered in *most significant digit* order, whereas the limbs themselves are in native least significant digit format. When representing the 64-bit word `0xAAAABBBBCCCCDDDD` using 32-bit words and precision fixed to 128 bits, I see:

```sh
% c++ limbs.cpp -lgmp -lmpfr -o limbs && ./limbs
ccccdddd|aaaabbbb|00000000|00000000
00000000|00000000|ccccdddd|aaaabbbb
```

This seems to imply that the in-memory representation can *not* be read back as a string of bits to recover the arbitrary precision number (e.g., if loaded this into a register on a machine that supported N*B sized words). Furthermore, this also seems to suggest that the limb size changes the representation, so that I would not be able to deserialize a number without knowing which limb size was used to serialize it.

Here's my test program (uses 32-bit limbs with the `__GMP_SHORT_LIMB` macro):

```cpp
#define __GMP_SHORT_LIMB
#include <gmp.h>
#include <mpfr.h>

#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

constexpr int PRECISION = 128;

void PrintLimbs(mp_limb_t const *const limbs) {
  std::cout << std::hex;
  constexpr int NUM_LIMBS = PRECISION / (8 * sizeof(mp_limb_t));
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LIMBS; ++i) {
    std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2 * sizeof(mp_limb_t)) << limbs[i];
    if (i < NUM_LIMBS - 1) {
      std::cout << "|";
    }
  }
  std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() {
  {  // GMP
    mpz_t num;
    mpz_init2(num, PRECISION);
    mpz_set_ui(num, 0xAAAABBBBCCCCDDDD);
    PrintLimbs(num->_mp_d);
    mpz_clear(num);
  }
  {  // MPFR
    mpfr_t num;
    mpfr_init2(num, PRECISION);
    mpfr_set_ui(num, 0xAAAABBBBCCCCDDDD, MPFR_RNDN);
    PrintLimbs(num->_mpfr_d);
    mpfr_clear(num);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Er, you know you can look at the sources (and documentation) of GMP if you really want to know? You are not supposed to look at that data directly, you can use a function like `mpz_export` to get something in the format you want. Why would it use some inconvenient memory representation that would force inverting the bytes every time it wants to read a limb?

Comment: I can only find brief mentions of this in the documentation, no thorough explanation/justification for the way the limbs are structured. I've looked at the sources and at the data (code above), which is what led to my confusion. I wasn't suggesting that the individual limbs should be inverted, but I don't understand why the order of limbs doesn't follow the order of bytes within each limb, so the number can be read in LSB order as a string of bits. I know it's supposed to be an opaque data type, but I need interoperability with the raw data for my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It finally clicked for me. The limb size does **not** affect the in-memory representation.

The data in GMP/MPFR *is* stored consistently in *little-endian* format, even when interpreted as a string of bytes across limbs. But registers on x86 are big-endian.

The inconsistent outcome when printing the limbs comes from how words are interpreted when read back from memory. When loaded into a register, memory is reinterpreted from little-endian (how it is stored in memory) to big-endian (how it is stored in registers).

I've modified the example below to show how it is in fact the *word size with which we reinterpret memory* that affects how the content is printed, as the output will be the same no matter if 32-bit or 64-bit limbs are used:

```cpp
#define __GMP_SHORT_LIMB
#include <gmp.h>
#include <mpfr.h>

#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

constexpr int PRECISION = 128;

template <typename InterpretAs>
void PrintLimbs(mp_limb_t const *const limbs) {
  constexpr int LIMB_BITS = 8 * sizeof(InterpretAs); 
  constexpr int NUM_LIMBS = PRECISION / LIMB_BITS;
  std::cout << LIMB_BITS << "-bit: ";
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LIMBS; ++i) {
    const auto limb = reinterpret_cast<InterpretAs const *>(limbs)[i];
    for (int b = 0; b < LIMB_BITS; ++b) {
      if (b > 0 && b % 16 == 0) {
        std::cout << " ";
      }
      uint64_t bit = (limb >> (LIMB_BITS - 1 - b)) & 0x1; 
      std::cout << bit; 
    }
    if (i < NUM_LIMBS - 1) {
      std::cout << "|";
    }
  }
  std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() {
  uint64_t literal = 0b1111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001001;
  {  // GMP
    mpz_t num;
    mpz_init2(num, PRECISION);
    mpz_set_ui(num, literal);
    std::cout << "GMP where limbs are interpreted as:\n";
    PrintLimbs<uint64_t>(num->_mp_d);
    PrintLimbs<uint32_t>(num->_mp_d);
    PrintLimbs<uint16_t>(num->_mp_d);
    mpz_clear(num);
  }
  {  // MPFR
    mpfr_t num;
    mpfr_init2(num, PRECISION);
    mpfr_set_ui(num, literal, MPFR_RNDN);
    std::cout << "MPFR where limbs are interpreted as:\n";
    PrintLimbs<uint64_t>(num->_mpfr_d);
    PrintLimbs<uint32_t>(num->_mpfr_d);
    PrintLimbs<uint16_t>(num->_mpfr_d);
    mpfr_clear(num);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This prints (regardless of limb size):

```
GMP where limbs are interpreted as:
64-bit: 1111000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001001|0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
32-bit: 0000000000000000 0000000000001001|1111000000000000 0000000000000000|0000000000000000 0000000000000000|0000000000000000 0000000000000000
16-bit: 0000000000001001|0000000000000000|0000000000000000|1111000000000000|0000000000000000|0000000000000000|0000000000000000|0000000000000000
MPFR where limbs are interpreted as:
64-bit: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000|1111000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001001
32-bit: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000|0000000000000000 0000000000000000|0000000000000000 0000000000001001|1111000000000000 0000000000000000
16-bit: 0000000000000000|0000000000000000|0000000000000000|0000000000000000|0000000000001001|0000000000000000|0000000000000000|1111000000000000
```

Answer (score 3):

3 things that matter for the byte representation:

- The limb size depends on your machine and the chosen ABI. The real size is also affected by the optional presence of *nails* (an experimental feature, thus it is unlikely that limbs have nails). MPFR does not support the presence of nails.
- The limb representation in memory follows the endianness of the machine.
- Limbs are stored least significant limb first (a.k.a. little endian).

Note that from the last two points, on a same big-endian machine, the byte representation of the array will depend on the limb size.

Concerning the size of the array of limbs, it depends on the type. For instance, with the mpn layer of GMP, it is entirely handled by the user.

For MPFR, the size is deduced from the precision of the `mpfr_t` object; and if the precision is not a multiple of the limb bitsize, the trailing bits are always set to 0. Note also that more memory may be allocated than the one actually used, and it must not be confused with the size of the array; you can ignore this fact, as the unused data are always after the actual array of limbs.

**EDIT** concerning the rationale: Manipulating limbs instead of bytes is for speed reasons. Then I suppose that little endian has been chosen to represent the array of limbs for two reasons. First, it makes the basic operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication) easier to implement and potentially faster. Second, this is much better to implement arithmetic modulo 2^*K*, in particular when *K* may change.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite an old post, but I feel something fairly crucial has been overlooked here.

You are comparing the limb structure of the (dynamic) arbitrary precision integer `mpz` and the (fixed) arbitrary precision float from `mpfr`. So it is not totally unexpected that the limb layout is different.

GMP is fairly explicit about the limb setup for `mpz`: the bits are stored in a dynamic array of the limb type `mp_limb_t` in little limb-endian order. (Note, while unlikely these days, the limb integers themselves could be stored in a different byte endianness.) Indeed it has to be this way so that limbs can be trivially copied when the limbs are resized. The limbs are allowed to grow dynamically to accommodate numbers that are too large to represent with the current limb arrangement.

MPFR is different. It is more similar to the IEEE 754 standard and the precision (read "number of limbs") of each number is set during the construction of the number. Once set, the precision does not change size by itself (typically, at least). This means that the size of the limb array is, for the purposes of computation, fixed and the size can be leveraged to use an arrangement that is more advantageous for the algorithms - I am speculating slightly, since I am not as familiar with ths mpfr internals. (Note that the limbs only store the mantissa bits, and the exponent is kept separately.) The limbs are still stored in little limb-endian order.

Details can be found in the documentation: https://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html#Internals
https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Internals.html